# return data in DetailTableView (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I have two table views. The first table view has a set number of cells. These cells will always be the same and will never change The above table view will always have the 4 cells and never more. On my server I have my API which has routes for each of these cells.

For example:

GET - myAPI/Air

GET - myAPI/history

GET - myAPI/train

GET - myAPI/taxi

And each routes send backs different data

> mainTablewView:

```
import UIKit
 enum NeededAPI {
case Air
case History
case Train
case Taxi
}
class mainTableViewController : UITableViewController {
struct WeatherSummary {
    var id: String
}

var testArray = NSArray()
var manuArray = NSArray()

// Array of sector within our company
var selectSector: [String] = ["Air", "History","Train","Taxi"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.selectSector.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sectorList", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    // Configure the cell...

    if selectSector.count > 0 {

        cell.textLabel?.text = selectSector[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "AirSegue"){
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? AirTableViewController {
            let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            if let row:Int = indexPath.row {

            destination.apiThatNeedsToBeCalled = .Air

            }


        }
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "HistorySegue"){
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? HistoryTableViewController {
            let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            if let row:Int = indexPath.row {

                destination.apiThatNeedsToBeCalled = .History

            }


        }
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "TrainSgue"){
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? TrainTableViewController {
            let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            if let row:Int = indexPath.row {

                destination.apiThatNeedsToBeCalled = .Train

            }


        }
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "TaxiSegue"){
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? TaxiTableViewController {
            let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            if let row:Int = indexPath.row {

                destination.apiThatNeedsToBeCalled = .Taxi

            }


        }
    }




}

}
```

> and Post

```
import Foundation
class Post : CustomStringConvertible {
var userId:Int
var title: String

init(userid:Int , title:String){
    self.userId = userid
    self.title = title
}

var description : String { return String(userId) }

}
```

When user selects cell you set the correct value for the apiThatNeedsToBeCalled. Once you do this, code inside the didSet will get executed and it should call the function which calls the appropriate API.

> to other tableView :

```
import UIKit

class AirTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var postCollection = [Post]()
        var apiThatNeedsToBeCalled:NeededAPI = .Air {
        didSet {
            //check which API is set and call the function which will call the needed API
            AirLine()

        }
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
var apiThatNeedsToBeCalled:NeededAPI = .Air {
    didSet {
        //check which API is set and call the function which will call the needed API
        AirLine()

    }
}

func AirLine(){

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){[unowned self] (data , respnse , error) in
        if error != nil{

            print(error!)
        }else{

            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

                var newPost = Iduser(id: 0)

                for posts in json {

                    let postObj = Post(userid:posts["userId"] as! Int,title: posts["title"] as! String)

                    self.postCollection.append(postObj)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }catch let error as NSError{

                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON:\(jsonStr)")

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Oops! Wrong Details, Try Again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


                }

            }

        }

    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.postCollection.count ?? 0
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AirCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    // cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

    let weatherSummary = postCollection[indexPath.row]


        cell.textLabel?.text = String(weatherSummary.userId)

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = weatherSummary.title




    return cell
}

}
```

mainTableView and Air cell  is Ok but when that selected other return The same information Air cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm just missing it, but I can see your creation of the NSURLSession looks fine, but I don't see where you're calling `.resume()` on that once you've created it.  If you don't call `.resume()` it'll never even perform that URLSession at all. Check the discussion [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:).

Comment: Why not bet my segue?? and just show .Air 
update code